# Can I combine fbx animations and view them in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, fbx

I have a site made with django. I want to add a function where I can select some animations, then those animations will be combined into one and a video player or something will play the combined animation. For example if the animations selected were "walk" and "jump", the combined animation played will be "walK" and then "jump". I've read about ways to play fbx files in a 3D viewer, but I'm not quite sure on specifics of how to do that. Also, I'm new to animations in general, so I'm still learning about them separately from the web development project.

So if I had a bunch of fbx files stored on my site, how can I go about implementing the function I described above, if possible?